# Android simple app doesn't start and do not know why

Tags: android, button, save, volume, seekbar

I have a problem regarding this simple program (actualy this is the single Activity/Class). This doesn't return me any error, it's simply doesn't start in emulator/device when run it.
It contains a seekBar(Ringer Volume Bar) and a OK button (to save the changes after seeking the Bar). I don't want a real-time seekBar(I mean when seek in the seekBar, automaticaly change the volume)

This is the code

```
public class Vol extends Activity {

public static final String TYPE = "TYPE";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras  = getIntent().getExtras();
    final int volumeType = extras != null ? extras.getInt(TYPE) : -1;
    final AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    String title = "Unknown Volume";

    if (volumeType != -1) {
        switch(volumeType) {
        case AudioManager.STREAM_RING:

            break;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setTitle(title);
        final SeekBar systemSeek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volume_bar);
        systemSeek.setMax(audio.getStreamMaxVolume(volumeType));
        systemSeek.setProgress(audio.getStreamVolume(volumeType));
        systemSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                final int setVolFlags = AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND | AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI;
                audio.setStreamVolume(volumeType,seekBar.getProgress(), setVolFlags);

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        Button ok  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (volumeType == AudioManager.STREAM_RING){
                    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                }
                finish();

            }
        });

    } else {
        finish();

    }

}
```

}

Could you please help me? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a number of things to consider here, like why are you using a switch statement, inside an if statement, with one option? Also, you are getting extra's, but from where? Is there another activity that is passing this activity data? I don't get this line: `final int volumeType = extras != null ? extras.getInt(TYPE) : -1;
`

Comment: @BlaineOmega About getting extras: No, i do not have another Activity, i took this from a tutorial . But, how can i define the volumeType to replace this line: `final int volumeType = extras != null ? extras.getInt(TYPE) : -1; ` ?

Comment: I can't explain that in a comment box. I usually don't recommend this, ever, but I'd say: start over. The best thing you can do as a developer is have something that works. Start with "hello world" and go from there. There is a lot missing from this to make it work, and at this point we would spend hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Cut -

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and paste just below -

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```